# Mysql count() fetches wrong result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the number of records for current week.
My current query is:

```
SELECT Week(Str_to_date(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y'), 1) AS order_week,
       Year(Str_to_date(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y')) AS order_year,
       order_active,
       Count(op.sub_order_id) AS deliveries
FROM   orders_products_attributes opa
       LEFT JOIN orders_products op
              ON ( opa.orders_products_id = op.orders_products_id )
GROUP  BY order_week,
          order_year
HAVING order_week = '31'
       AND order_year >= '2013'
       AND order_active = 0
ORDER  BY order_week
```

It fetches `deliveries` AS `2` where as there are actually 4 records, and if I run the same query after removing `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`, it correctly shows all 4 rows. The same problem happens on other weeks too, for example week 34 has 3 records, but the above query fetches it as 4 instead. Moreover, another weird thing is, in the `GROUP BY` clause, if I remove either one of `order_week` or `order_year` the query returns an empty result set.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: some sample data would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move all HAVING conditions into WHERE. Also `Count(id)` - counts UNIQUE values of ID not all. If you need all records count just use `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT Week(Str_to_date(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y'), 1) AS order_week,
       Year(Str_to_date(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y')) AS order_year,
       order_active,
       Count(op.sub_order_id) AS deliveries
FROM   orders_products_attributes opa
       LEFT JOIN orders_products op
              ON ( opa.orders_products_id = op.orders_products_id )
WHERE order_week = '31'
       AND order_year >= '2013'
       AND order_active = 0

GROUP  BY order_week,
          order_year
ORDER  BY order_week
```

Comment: Since order_week and order_year are aliases, I can't put them in WHERE. and all sub_order_ids are unique, but I tried with * as well, and it returned same error

Comment: @aoi  Ok then just move `order_active = 0` condition into where

Comment: The main issue was actually that there was an actual column named order_week...

However moving order_active to WHERE also helped...thanks